# Adding the calculated values to an empty column based on index stored in a variable using python

Tags: python, indexing, append, export-to-excel, calculated-columns

I am relatively new in programming and this is the first python code I have made.

This is a code I used for calculation. I have managed to calculate the values and they can be seen in the variable "HT". But I am struggling with appending it to the Dataframe "poll" in the "Heat Category" column using the index in the variable "ind". After getting the values to the column, I won't have a problem exporting it to excel file.

With this code, I keep getting multiple data frames for each calculated value with the same value throughout the "Heat Category" column, and it keeps repeating for another calculated value. I think the appending to the column must be done one-by-one based on the index, and I must get a single data frame at the end but I am not sure how. I have looked through many previous questions and solutions on the internet, but I have failed to find a solution for my case.

Can anyone please help me?

```
import pandas as pd

#assigning range
AHi =[50,100,150,200,300]
ALo=[0,51,101,151,201]
CHi=[20,40,60,160,260]
CLo=[0,20.1,40.1,60.1,160.1]

poll=pd.read_excel("C:/Compiled sheet.xlsx")

x = poll[['Temp_Avg']]
y = poll[['Heat Category']]

x_num=len(x)
print(x_num)

i=0
for i in range(x_num):
    heat = x.iloc[i]['Temp_Avg'] #extracting all data from the column Temp_Avg

    len_num=0
    len_num=len(AHi)
    for j in range(len_num):
        if heat<CHi[j] and heat>=CLo[j]: #finding out the range in which the values lie
            z=(CLo[j])
        
            ind=CLo.index(z) #finding out the index
        
            CH=CHi[ind]
            CL=CLo[ind]
            AH=AHi[ind]
            AL=ALo[ind]

            #calculation
            try:
                y=((AH-AL)+(CH-CL))*(heat-CL)
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                print ('NA')
            HT=int(round(y,0))
        
            #trial to add the values to the column Heat Category
            #poll.loc[[ind], 'Heat Category'] = HT
            #print (poll)
        
            poll.loc[:,'Heat Category'] = HT
            print(poll)
```

Expected output

```
     Temp_Avg   Heat Category
     175.77      382   
     163.59      428
     135.97      498

 and so on.....
```

Comment: would you care to share the .xlsx file on poll=pd.read_excel("C:/Compiled sheet.xlsx")

Comment: Here is the link to the excel file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tSoDFBBrBJOfXbV_mRbGyJ-vlAHCb-e5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: is the eq. y=((AH-AL)+(CH-CL))*(heat-CL) available online? please paste an online link for reference. thank you

Comment: Hi Ruperto. Thank you for your reply. The calculation part is not a problem. I just need to find a way to append it to the column. Can you help me with that?

Comment: okay Stha please see the adjusted indentations below. Also 2nd to the last line was modified. please try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please note the indentations on the lines below were adjusted.

```
    #calculation
    try:
        y=((AH-AL)+(CH-CL))*(heat-CL)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print ('NA')
    HT=int(round(y,0))
        
    #trial to add the values to the column Heat Category
    #poll.loc[[ind], 'Heat Category'] = HT
    #print (poll)
        
    poll['Heat Category'].iloc[i] = HT # This line was modified
print(poll)
```

also the 2nd to the last line was modified

result:

```
   Temp_Avg  Heat Category
0    175.77         3117.0
1    163.59          694.0
2    135.97        11297.0
3    124.88         9646.0
```

and so on...